# request advice converting project to node.js

Tags: node.js

Our company processes machine data. We get machine reports from a socket connection and write the data to mysql tables. Then, other scripts and threads written in python and ruby pull these records out and process the data, saving them back to the database and notify our clients on their machines health.

I want to convert these processes to node.js But, i have to do it kinda incrementally. Instead of doing so much writing back and forth to the database, I would like to hand the data off from our input process to a node server, that will process everything at once.

I suppose i can modify our input scripts to hand off the raw bytes we get from the machines or I could process them as JSON. I had thought about writing the new processes using a node http server, but that seems like some overhead. I have thought websockets may be a better solution, but I am looking for ideas.. thanks

Comment: Generally in projects like these it is best to allow multiple capture pipelines so you can prove the process works before shutting the other one off.  And to answer your question with a question, what real reason do you have to rewrite it if it works?

Comment: performance, mostly. It is a system that works, but is constantly evolving. I want to be able to share more code. The performance issue is that some of these processes spawn external ruby and python scripts that load, connect to the DB, process data and save and exit themselves every time a machine reports. The async nature of javascript should be helpful in processing data faster also, as we are doing everything sequentially now. OK when we started, but getting unmanagable as we grow